# SUM of multiple columns text in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, multiple-columns

Is the first time writing a command in excel so I have no particular idea what I'm doing.

As you can see from the image I'm trying to get in the "All Stores" column all the Stores that have the "X" in them.

At the moment the command that I'm using is displaying the output of the first cell where it finds an "X".

I have looked at some examples that I found on this topic, but I didn't find something concrete. I've tried to do it with "SUMIF" and also I've tried to use "&" in from and after "B2", "C2", "D2", but all I got was an error.

Everything that I found on this topic was how to combine numbers.

In this particular example the expected result would be "Store1, Store3".

Thank you for your support!

[image: Product Store Example]

Answer (score 0):

Yyou could use the following:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B2="x",B$1,""),IF(C2="x",C$1,""),IF(D2="x",D$1,""))
```

And populate down for other products

Though it could get unwieldy if you have a lot of stores. I'm pretty sure someone else will come up with a more clever answer, but I can't think of anything else at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In **E2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=CHOOSE(COUNTA(B2:D2)+1,"",INDEX(B$1:D$1,MATCH("x",B2:D2,0)),TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B2:D2="x",B$1:D$1,"")),"All stores")
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

The logic is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've tried to use the example provided by you, but it will return with 2 error($NAME! or $VALUE). It might be possible that the range that I need is to big. For my actual spreadsheet I'm going from C2:BK2 (60 cells in total). Is there another method which can support such a broad range?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I image you have over several columns that you want to consider. SO you can get this date in a new worksheet by replacing "x" or a mark of choice using below formula:
`=IF(A2<>"", A$1, "")` just autofill to get all the values in the new worksheet.

Now focussing on the new worksheet. e.g.
[image: New Worksheet data]

Apply below formula to get the required result

`=IF(COUNTA(H2:J2)-COUNTBLANK(H2:J2)=COLUMNS(H2:J2),"All Stories",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,H2:J2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX($A$1:$F$1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(B2:F2="X")*COLUMN(B2:F2),N(IF(1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(B2:F2)))))))),"")
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you just explain what is (15,6,1)? In my actual spreadsheet I have from B2:BK2="X" and I'm not entirely sure with what I should replace that (15,6,1)

Comment: @H.Sam You should do some reading about basic Excel to understand the syntax of parameters for functions. Then examine **HELP** for the `AGGREGATE` function for the specific meaning of those first two arguments.  The `1/(…` portion of the array parameter converts `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `DIV/0` errors which can be ignored by the `AGGREGATE` function.  You would then understand why you do not replace `15,6,1` with anything.